# Error en puntero de array c++

Tags: c++, array, punteros

Basicamente me tira error en las ultimas lineas del codigo, denro de la funcion multiplicar, pero no se que es. El programa se trata sobre multiplicar matrices, pero el error no esta dentro de la logica de la multiplicacion, sino en el uso de punteros. Si o si tengo que usar punteros para hacer este problema. Gracias <3

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

void Multiplicar(int *A, int *B, int *C, int n, int c, int m);

int main(){
    int n, c, m, x, y, **A, **B;

    cout << "introduce el valor de n: "; cin >> n;
    cout << "introduce el valor de c: "; cin >> c;
    cout << "introduce el valor de m: "; cin >> m;

    cout << "\nArray A: " << endl;
    A= new int *[n];
    for(x=1; x<=n; x++){//rows
        A[x]= new int [c];
        for(y=1; y<=c; y++){//columns
            A[x][y]= rand()%198 + -99;
            cout << A[x][y] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << "\nArray B: " << endl;
    B= new int *[c];
    for(x=1; x<=c; x++){//rows
        B[x]= new int [m];
        for(y=1; y<=m; y++){//columns
            B[x][y]= rand()%198 + -99;
            cout << B[x][y] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    int **C;
    C= new int *[n];
    for(x=0; x<n; x++){//rows
        C[x]= new int [m];
    }

    Multiplicar(*A, *B, *C, n, c, m);

    return 0;
}
void Multiplicar(int *A, int *B, int *C, int n, int c, int m){
    int x, y, k;

    cout << "Matriz c: " << endl;

    for(x=0; x<n; x++){
        for(y=0; y<m; y++){
            C[x][&y]=0;
            for(k=0; k<n; k++){
                C[x][&y]+=(A[x][&k]*B[k][&y]);
            }
            cout << C[x][&y] << " " << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Esto es lo que me sale en cosola(tuve que eliminar la parte donde se imprimen las matrices A y B porque me decia que enia mucho codigo):

```
introduce el valor de n: 3
introduce el valor de c: 4
introduce el valor de m: 5

Matriz c:
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Si haces  C[x][&y]=0;  Pero si utilizas &y o &k estás tomando como  indice la 
dirección de memoria  donde esta y  o k, por lo tanto, te estás saliendo de los limites de memoria. Lo correcto sería C[x][y].

Comment: Compílalo con `-fsanitize=address`, y coloca mensajes indicando que es lo que estas haciendo en cada paso. Entonces veras donde es que estas tocando memoria que no te toca.

Answer (score 0):

> Si o si tengo que usar punteros para hacer este problema.

**MENTIRA**. Usar punteros es enfarragoso, complicado, sucio y propenso a errores. [Si o si tengo que **NO usar punteros** para hacer este problema](https://tio.run/##rVPRbpswFH3GX3HVagksVEq1TVoKQQKe9wVtHlxDKguwkTEodMq3Z9fEFNJmqjTtAYPPOb733OsLq@s7VlLxcjrdcsHKNssh5LLRKqdVRCaMNTor@fMc6nKmpYoIaRsuXkDQKm9qynJAaTCie15S2MJZG3Kho8AyFdWKv06cUSJJOskz@NWWmtclZ1S5TIpGj/JF7MMlkPhvn6kPmAHE@cXOr8rDoLYiWMg6V9SkC90Jex@y8shv4uylApuctlrCYg8PGI04yH0kOyT3SDqOhDCEzixLWAbEAssnYTZHQhyV61YJkAHB3WCRcuF6gHGtfbReoWuHyVabwzeIK5m12Ny8hI6WmB2vQDzATQCMC4giEMGnejbXs8/11Vx/aehJxErRHmKUGCAXWYkBbQdjF4swF@piJWvP3MC5Y1MjY2/s4vv@dTgTiorM9b7cb37CCu42m5nX@KqP5KqPxOQffFR/85H8q4/EBLN50rd6xzzOfIJxZnFKcTrt1XpXS0gvSxj5NJhGZj2MzP//Q8bRO/jQ@1DYNrmH7TqAQyhwWa08O/Zub9A@rHCxqJM@HnaP/Q4JszOiwogKc7QYRaNqtXVj81Xsvia4IOINx45keI7keDp9I9/JD/IH):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

using fila = vector<int>;
using matriz = vector<fila>;

void Multiplicar(const matriz &A, const matriz &B, matriz &C, int n, int c, int m);

ostream &operator<<(ostream &o, const matriz &m)
{
    for (const auto &f : m)
    {
        for (const auto &v : f)
            o << v << ' ';
        o << '\n';
    }

    return o;
}

int main() {
    int n, c, m;

    cout << "introduce el valor de n: "; cin >> n;
    cout << "introduce el valor de c: "; cin >> c;
    cout << "introduce el valor de m: "; cin >> m;

    cout << "\nArray A: " << endl;
    matriz A(n, fila(c, 0));

    for (auto &f : A)
        for (auto &v : f)
            v = rand()%198 + -99;
    cout << A;

    cout << "\nArray B: " << endl;
    matriz B(c, fila(m, 0));

    for (auto &f : B)
        for (auto &v : f)
            v = rand()%198 + -99;
    cout << B;

    matriz C(n, fila(m, 0));
    Multiplicar(A, B, C, n, c, m);

    cout << "\nArray C: " << endl;
    cout << C;

    return 0;
}

void Multiplicar(const matriz &A, const matriz &B, matriz &C, int n, int c, int m) {
    int x, y, k;

    for(x=0; x<n; x++){
        for(y=0; y<m; y++){
            C[x][y]=0;
            for(k=0; k<n; k++){
                C[x][y]+=(A[x][k]*B[k][y]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

El operador et se puede usar para obtener la dirección de memoria de una variable:

```
int a;
int *direccion = &a;
```

Una dirección de memoria es un número de 32 o 64 bits que apunta a la zona de RAM donde la variable guarda sus datos, esta dirección de memoria puede interpretarse como un número:

```
int a;
int *direccion = &a;
long b = reinterpret_cast<long>(direccion);

std::cout
    << "a: " << a << '\n'
    << "direccion: " << direccion << '\n'
    << "b: " << b << '\n';
```

El código anterior [muestra la siguiente salida](https://tio.run/##VU7RCoMwDHw2XxEcTB0M9qzVLxmMGIsUNJVan8a@vWuZc@wlyd3lcuFlufJEMoZwMsLTNmhUxq7eaZo7ACMeZzJSVvAEyBKk5tMvg3Ga2VjBFs@JnayM2EfkdFzQbnHaP5hWr5LSlYehauKt1Q91zXbzkGVKYU415hgHSqW4S7Hzh2vXf7H/e/2u918@hcQPNid4a@AVwhs)<sup>1</sup>:

> ```
> a: 0
> direccion: 0x7ffc158a6108
> b: 140720669876488
> ```

Como puedes ver, el valor de la dirección de la variable `a` es enorme: ciento cuarenta billones setecientos veinte mil seiscientos sesenta y nueve millones ochocientos setenta y seis mil cuatrocientos ochenta y ocho<sup>1</sup>.

Ninguno de tus formaciones<sup>2</sup> tiene tantas posiciones, por lo tanto este código es incorrecto:

```
for(x=0; x<n; x++){
    for(y=0; y<m; y++){
        C[x][&y]=0;
//           ^ <--- DISPARATE!
        for(k=0; k<n; k++){
            C[x][&y]+=(A[x][&k]*B[k][&y]);
//               ^          ^        ^
//                \          \        \___ RIDÍCULO!
//                 \          \___ ABSURDO!
//                  \___ INSENSATEZ!
        }
        cout << C[x][&y] << " " << endl;
//                   ^ <--- BLASFEMIA!
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup>El valor de la dirección de memoria, probablemente cambie en cada ejecución

<sup>2</sup>También conocidas como *arreglos* o en inglés *arrays*.

Comment: Hombre. Será un ejercicio de clase. Por eso la exigencia de punteros :-)

Comment: Si en clase están enseñando con punteros, están haciendo perder el tiempo a los alumnos y a los profesionales que en el futuro trabajen con esos alumnos.

Comment: Tranqui bro, es un ejercicicio de clase y no se como hacerlo con punteros(me piden que sea asi). Gracias por la respuesta, pero trata de ser menos agresivo con otras personas.

Comment: Estoy la mar de tranquilo, bro. Mi comentario no denota agresividad alguna si no que describe una triste y dura realidad: si te están enseñando [tag:c++] usando y abusando de punteros, te están haciendo perder el tiempo y a no ser que cambien las prácticas de enseñanza, harán perder el tiempo a todo aquel con quien colabores en un proyecto.